# Foreign Key Constraint Conflict, yet rows still insert?

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, sql-server-2012

Good Day

I am having a weird morning with this SQL script - I am getting the following errors (as this script is a script used to fill tables up with dummy data):

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ATTR". The conflict occurred in database "PhonebookDuplication", table "dbo.Attributes_Dummy", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

As the question suggests, the rows in this table still gets inserted (as if it is not enforcing the foreign key constraints)

I also tested manually inserting data - it does not throw this error then.

Here are the layouts of my tables and the script which I execute.  I need to know what is going on, and why it throws an error please :) I bet its something obvious which I am overlooking.

[image: Table Layout]

script:

```
use PhonebookDuplication;

DROP TABLE Numbers_Attributes_Bridge;
DROP TABLE Numbers_Dummy;
DROP TABLE Attributes_Dummy;


CREATE TABLE Numbers_Dummy
            (
             Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
             Number VARCHAR(20),
             AccountId INT,
             FirstName VARCHAR(20),
             LastName VARCHAR(20)
            );


CREATE TABLE Attributes_Dummy
            (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
             AccountId INT,
             Attribute VARCHAR(100)
            );

CREATE TABLE Numbers_Attributes_Bridge
            ( 
              NumberId int,
              AttributeId int,
              AccountId int,
              Value Varchar(100)
              CONSTRAINT PK_NA PRIMARY KEY
              (
                  NumberId ASC,
                  AttributeId ASC
              )
              CONSTRAINT FK_Numbers FOREIGN KEY (NumberId) REFERENCES Numbers_Dummy(Id),
              CONSTRAINT FK_ATTR FOREIGN KEY (AttributeId) REFERENCES Attributes_Dummy(Id),
            );

DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 0;
SET NOCOUNT ON
WHILE (@COUNTER < 150) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Numbers_Dummy VALUES ('082'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@Counter),2000046,'Eon','du Plessis')
    SET @COUNTER += 1;
END

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Numbers_Dummy

SET @COUNTER = 0;
WHILE (@COUNTER < 5)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Attributes_Dummy VALUES (2000046,'Attribute'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@Counter))
    SET @COUNTER += 1;
END 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Attributes_Dummy

DECLARE @COUNTER2 INT = 0 ;
DECLARE @SUBCOUNTER INT = 0; 
WHILE (@COUNTER2 <= 150)
BEGIN
    WHILE (@SUBCOUNTER <= 5)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Numbers_Attributes_Bridge VALUES (@COUNTER2,@SUBCOUNTER,2000046, 'ATTRIBUTE-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@SUBCOUNTER))
        SET @SUBCOUNTER =@SUBCOUNTER + 1;
    END
    SET @SUBCOUNTER = 0;
    SET @COUNTER2 = @COUNTER2 + 1;
END
```

Logic Says that the numbers_dummy table will have 150 rows, ID = 1 to 150
                    attributes will have 5 rows, ID = 1 - 5 
                    Numbers_Attributes_Bridge should have 750 rows: NumberID = 1 to 150 with a compound primary key value of AttributeID = 1 to 5

I am getting the abovementioned error, but rows still insert.

The following line of code did not throw an error on a manual test:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers_Attributes_Bridge VALUES (150,5,2000046, 'ATTRIBUTE-5')
```

What is going on?

Comment: Start your counters from 1, not 0.

Comment: Will try (15 Character Padding)

Comment: Same Situation. Still getting the errors, but data still inserts

Comment: Actually. this was weird. I set the counters to 1, ran it, error. Took Sergio's script, ran it, worked.  

/giveup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo messed up with counters, try following script:

```
DECLARE @COUNTER INT = 1;
SET NOCOUNT ON
WHILE (@COUNTER <= 150) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Numbers_Dummy VALUES ('082'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@Counter),2000046,'Eon','du Plessis')
    SET @COUNTER += 1;
END

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Numbers_Dummy

SET @COUNTER = 1;
WHILE (@COUNTER <= 5)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Attributes_Dummy VALUES (2000046,'Attribute'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@Counter))
    SET @COUNTER += 1;
END 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Attributes_Dummy

DECLARE @COUNTER2 INT = 1 ;
DECLARE @SUBCOUNTER INT = 1; 
WHILE (@COUNTER2 <= 150)
BEGIN
    WHILE (@SUBCOUNTER <= 5)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Numbers_Attributes_Bridge VALUES (@COUNTER2,@SUBCOUNTER,2000046, 'ATTRIBUTE-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@SUBCOUNTER))
        SET @SUBCOUNTER =@SUBCOUNTER + 1;
    END
    SET @SUBCOUNTER = 1;
    SET @COUNTER2 = @COUNTER2 + 1;
END
```

You're getting errors when trying to insert row with NumberId or AttributeId = 0, but all other rows are inserted well, that's why you have some records inserted

Comment: the reason of me asking was because I had to change the 150 to 1.5 million, and every single loop that ran threw the error into the messages tab, and completely screwed over the performance of this already long-running script

Comment: Turns out by using INSERT INTO <Table> SELECT <Table2> .....  CROSS JOIN <Table3> Inserts rows around 5 times faster than using while loops. but that was not the purpose of my test, just came across it